# really slow login on ubuntu-18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, login-screen

just installed ubuntu 18.04 on my new computer. the OS is dual booted next to win10. the OS is installed on SSD, and so the boot takes about 10 second.
when I get to the login window, and after typing my password, it takes around 35 seconds to get the desktop (purple screen meanwhile).
tried and failed to find the logs of this process to see what's taking so long.

- happens only on first login after boot
- tried creating an other user. same issue
- tried disabling floppy-disk on BIOS (don't have this option- Lenovo IdeaPad S540)
- installed my OS with a 1GB swap drive

Answer (score 0):

I suspected the problem is with Nvidia GPU. checked dmesg and found there are really a lot of timeouts to the "nouveau" driver.
used [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu) guide to update my driver to more compatible Nvidia driver. Boot now takes ~7 seconds, and login after inserting password ~7-8 more.